# cell.imageView is working on Simulator but not on Device

Tags: iphone, cell, imageview

Table view cell imageView is working on the simulator but not on the device..
Some things I have checked.
I have not changed anything in the code.
Image is added to the project and in same folder.
I have one more cell image which is working fine.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iphone device is case sensitive ... and simulator is not..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the case of the name used in your +[UIImage imageNamed:] calls. These are case-sensitive on the device, but not always on the sim. That's the most common cause of missing images. If that isn't the source, put a breakpoint where you're assigning the image, and check all teh variables.