# iPod running 4.2 background image has slight error, when iPhone simulator 4.2 is fine

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an interesting problem. My app runs fine on the iphone 4.2 simulator, everything works as i expect. However when I put it onto my ipod to test it out it seems to have one slight background image problem.

The background that i have loaded in using interface builder displays correctly, however, when I try to run this code, the ipod does not display it...

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"v3_default_bg.png"];
UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
bgView.image = img;
[appDelegate.navigationController.view addSubview:bgView];
[appDelegate.navigationController.view sendSubviewToBack:bgView];
```

Could anyone shed some light on this for me? that would be really great! Thanks.

**edit**

Actually I have found that the uiimage is returning null on only iOS devices. On the simulator it works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"v3_default_bg"]` instead (that is, without the `".png"` extension in the filename)?

Comment: I thought that it needed the .png. Guess not. But still no luck. Although I did try it on my iPad and didn't have any success there either

Comment: Potentially silly question, but do you include the actual image with your deploy? I don't know if it does it automatically or what, might be worth looking into. Other than that not sure what it could be

Comment: Well I would assume that it's included all my other images are. But I ran a quick test and when running on my iPad the uiimageview.image returns null in the log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It turns out that on the simulator, image names are not case sensitive. But on devices they are...

Comment: haha I just returned to add this to my answer... Just had the same issue today :)

Answer (score 1):

You might check the Copy Bundle Resources settings under your target -> Build phases -> last section 'Copy Bundle Resources' is there an entry for the image? If not you need to create one by clicking the '+' button and select your image. 
Or check the case sensitivity. iPhone simulator does ignore the cases - the device does NOT!
Same as in this question [cell.imageView is working on Simulator but not on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743844/cell-imageview-is-working-on-simulator-but-not-on-device).